# adding another module dependency in angularjs, the application stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I ran into a weird problem that I could not figure out, I could not get a good explanation even after searching on the internet.

I have a application (webpage) which consists of ui-bootstrap's accrodion element which gets the data from a json file by $http request. This part is working perfectly fine. Now I wanted to add a multiselect dropdown and I wanted to use the element provided in ui-select. But when I add the dependencies 'ngSanitize' and 'ui-select' in the module, the application doesn't work. I haven't added any dropdown elements, just the dependencies. I don't understand where the problem is.

The original application controller

```
var app = angular.module('callApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('firstController', function($scope, $http, $modal, $log) {
    //some functions are defined here
});
angular.module('callApp').service('popupService', function () {
    //service is defined
});
```

Then i added the dependencies ngSanitize and ui.select

```
var app = angular.module('callApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);
app.controller('firstController', function($scope, $http, $modal, $log) {
    //some functions are defined here
});
angular.module('callApp').service('popupService', function () {
    //service is defined
});
```

Now the application doesn't work. I haven't modified any other function or added any elements in the html. Why does such a problem arrive? Is there anything wrong with the declaration?

Comment: What error does it give in the console if any?

Comment: Just checking the obvious - did u bower install and add a <script src=""> in your html for those modules?

Comment: It does not give any error, the elements are not displayed. I tried $log.info("hi") inside the controller, but that part is not executed. I have done bower install and added script src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the reference to the js files to your html page too?

What errors do you see in the console (press F12)?

If the reference to the js files exist in your html then just check the paths are correctly pointing to the actual path.

Regards,

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: And that should be a comment against the question, not your (non)answer.

Comment: @swordfish12, when you say elements are not displayed, do you mean you see a blank page or the page partially loads?  For debug purposes use the non minified angular.js reference in your html file to get detailed error message.

Comment: So you think it's a good idea to post an answer to get around the restrictions? Those blocks are there for a reason and it's pretty simple to get the 50 reputation to post comments. You should go and do that first.

Comment: What are you going on about!  I'm new to Stack Overflow and am simply trying to help solve the problem.  I'm not trying to get  around any restrictions and see no benefit to me in what I've done?!  I'm not interested in points just bettering myself by helping others and learning with them.  Your last comment in my eyes resembles the chicken or egg question.  Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: I applaud your efforts to try to help someone. But you are effectively abusing the system by posting an answer that is not an answer. I suggest you try to answer a question properly to get reputation or suggest some edits. It doesn't take much effort to get to the 50 points required.

Comment: the page does not load at all, none of the elements are displayed.

Comment: @swordfish12, in that case I'm pretty sure its due to how you're referencing it.  Can you show us the <script src=""> section you have in your html file please.  Oh and can you try removing reference to 'ngSanitize' (leave 'ui.select') then visa versa to make sure its not just one dependency that's failing?

Comment: That seemed to have been the problem, thanks for helping me out.